# Javascript: For loop isn't working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dynamic, datatables

So I think there's something wrong with my for loop somewhere...

I have all the classes on a separate css file so I'm seeing everything on the DOM correctly on the front end.

My problem is that I need to make rows 1 and 3 have apply this class and I can get it work:

```
<i class="fa fa fa-trophy fa-4" aria-hidden="true">
```

In theory, I'm supposed to have a dynamic data table with 10 rows which are users in our app that came in first through tenth.

Rows 1-3: Are the users that came in first, second and third place... hence they get the "fa-trophy" class.

Rows 4-10: Are the remaining users hence they get the "fa-user-circle-o" class.

What am I doing wrong?

Javascript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.leaderboards.length; i++){

        row = $('<div class="leaderboard-row">');
        row.append('<div class="user-circle"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-4" aria-hidden="true">' + '</i></div>');
        row.append('<div class="leaderboard-col col1">' + (i + 1) + '</div>');
        row.append('<div class="leaderboard-col col2"><span class="truncate">' + data.leaderboards[i].username + '</span></div>');
        row.append('<div class="leaderboard-col col3"><span class="truncate">' + data.leaderboards[i].win_amount.formatMoney(0, '.', ',') + '</span></div>');

        if(data.leaderboards[i].level_unlocked > _currLevel){
            row.append('<div class="leaderboard-col col4">Won Playing ' + data.leaderboards[i].game_name + '</div>');
        }
        else{
            row.append('<div class="leaderboard-col col4">Won Playing <a href="/game/' + data.leaderboards[i].game_slug + '">' + data.leaderboards[i].game_name + '</a></div>');
        }
        _table.append(row);
    }
```

Comment: can you provide `data` detail please.

Comment: data.leaderboards is this array?

Comment: @Natsathorn I don't have my machine with the exact answer at the moment  but "data" is hitting the backend and grabbing info from the " .leaderboards" database. We have this connected Django if that helps.

Comment: @ Dinesh Yes it's an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you assign the `fa-trophy` class when `i <= 2` ? Something like

```
if (i <= 2) {
    // assign fa-trophy class for the first 3 places
    row.append('<div class="user-circle"><i class="fa fa-trophy fa-4" aria-hidden="true">' + '</i></div>');
} else {
    // do something else with 4th place onwards
    row.append('<div class="user-circle"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-4" aria-hidden="true">' + '</i></div>');
}
```

Comment: Holy crap! That should work! Will rows 4-10 populate correctly?

Comment: Yes. This will work for rows 4-n, where `n` is `data.leaderboards.length`.

Comment: What if I want to give row 2 a different class name as well? So in theory any users coming in second place receive a bronze medal which would be a different "i class"?

Comment: You have access to the indices in the for loop. So you can choose to do whatever you like with whichever index you choose. In your case, maybe you can check `i === 2` and do something there. If you have too many such specific cases, I would suggest you create a function called `getUserCircleClasses` which accepts an integer and returns a string with all the classes you want to add. And use this string to assign the `i` tag class.

Comment: I'm at work and this worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help! :)